# Block "catalog/product_list_random" shows no products in CMS

Tags: magento2, blocks, catalog, cms, random

I'm using Magento 2.0.2.

I want to display a random collection of products from the catalog on my home page.  In the *CMS for my home page*, i use the following code:

```
<p>{{block type="catalog/product_list_random" template="catalog/product/list.phtml" num_products="12"}}</p>

<hr />

<p>{{widget type="Magento\CatalogWidget\Block\Product\ProductsList" products_count="4" template="product/widget/content/grid.phtml" conditions_encoded="a:1:[i:1;a:4:[s:4:`type`;s:50:`Magento|CatalogWidget|Model|Rule|Condition|Combine`;s:10:`aggregator`;s:3:`all`;s:5:`value`;s:1:`1`;s:9:`new_child`;s:0:``;]]"}}</p>
```

The `product_list_random` block displays nothing, but the widget displays products just as I would expect.

Why does the block render nothing at all?  How can I display a collection of random products on the home page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the attribute `class` instead of `type`. Magento 2 got rid of class aliases such as `core/template` or `core/text_list`

```
{{block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Random" template="product/list.phtml" num_products="12"}}
```

This will work